# Html <form> with 2 submits. Whatever you choose sends the value of the first one

Tags: html, jsp

I have an html  with 2 submit inputs but it doesn't matter if you press the first or the second.

```
<div class="table">

<%
ResultSet resultados = ...
while (resultados.next()) {
%>

<div class="row">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="ProcesarForm(this,'productosAdmin','admin2');return false"> // this = the form, productosAdmin = servlet name, admin2 = name of the div to display the response

    <div class="cell maxcol">
        <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Producto" name="tipoOper" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell maxcol">
        <input type="submit" value="Borrar Producto" name="tipoOper" />
        </div>
</form>
</div>

    <%
        }
    %>
</div>
```

But on the servlet always reads

```
String tipoOper = request.getParameter("tipoOper");
```

tipoOper always is "Actualizar Producto";

Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont you put different name on the input tag name ? then use if else condition on your submit page

Answer (score 0):

Form fields should have unique name attributes unless they are part of a group, like a group of radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest naming the submit buttons differently and on the server side checking for the existence of either one and getting the value of the one that is set.